# Draw a rectangle bounding offline human hand written signatures

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a project that detects offline human hand written signatures. I am using opencv version 2.4.10 and C++ as the programming language. I am stuck with a situation where in I want to draw a rectangular box bounding the signature. My output should be four coordinates that if used, CvRectangle function, I can draw it. I used bounded box method, but its giving me wrong output. its creating multiple bounded boxes for the same image. And that is because the signature is not continuous and its contours highly vary. I need a single right-angled rectangle that borders the signature.

Comment: Union the boxes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for each contour find the [boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html) and perform union operation.
The complete [list of operations](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=rect#Rect_) on rectangles is

```
// In addition to the class members, the following operations 
// on rectangles are implemented:

// (shifting a rectangle by a certain offset)
// (expanding or shrinking a rectangle by a certain amount)
rect += point, rect -= point, rect += size, rect -= size (augmenting operations)
rect = rect1 & rect2 (rectangle intersection)
rect = rect1 | rect2 (minimum area rectangle containing rect2 and rect3 )
rect &= rect1, rect |= rect1 (and the corresponding augmenting operations)
rect == rect1, rect != rect1 (rectangle comparison)


  [1]: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=rect#Rect_
```